# How to make multiple spring boot projects dependency work with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am just using [spring boot initializer](http://start.spring.io/) to create base and sub two projects and using the most simple multiple projects. I set settings.gradle at root to **include 'base','sub'**. I also add **compile project(':base')** dependency in sub/gradle.build. When I run **gradle build** in root folder it will always failed when execute :sub:compileJave task and report can't find some package from base project. And the strange is when I directly run **gradlew :sub:compileJava** in root folder it will succeed. Any body can tell me what it correct way to make **gradlew build** work?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. Because default the spring boot jar is "fat" jar that is not able be referenced directly on the class path. The solution is simple just add 
bootRepackage.enabled=false in base project that won't run gradle task bootRepackage and keep the ordinary jar package left and that can be referenced by the other project.